# Which properties does tensorial product have with respect to scalar product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Are the associative and distributive properties preserved?

In Cohen-Tannoudji's *Mécanique quantique vol. I*, the scalar product in the $\epsilon=\epsilon_1 \otimes\epsilon_2$ space is defined as follows:

> $\gamma.$ The scalar product in $\mathscr E$
>
> The existence of the scalar products in $\mathscr E_1$ and $\mathscr E_2$ permits us to define one in $\mathscr E$ as well. We first define the scalar product of $|\phi(1)\chi(2)\rangle = |\phi(1)\rangle \otimes |\chi(2)\rangle$ by $|\phi'(1)\chi'(2)\rangle = |\phi'(1)\rangle \otimes |\chi'(2)\rangle$ by setting:
> $$
> \langle\phi'(1)\chi'(2)|\phi(1)\chi(2)\rangle = \langle\phi'(1)|\phi(1)\rangle \ \langle\chi'(2) |\chi(2)\rangle
> \tag{F-8}
> $$
> For two arbitrary vectors in $\mathscr E$, we simply use the fundamental properties of the scalar product [equations (B-9), (B-10) and (B-11)], since each of these vectors is a linear combination of tensor product vectors.

With $|\phi(1)\rangle$ expressed in the orthonormal basis ${|u(1)\rangle}$ of the space $\epsilon_1$ and $|\chi(2)\rangle$ expressed in the orthonormal basis ${|u(2)\rangle}$ of the space $\epsilon_2$.

I ask this to know if (F-8) equation can be deduced or not from those properties. Could the following be done in order of this?

$$\begin{cases}
|\psi\chi\rangle=|\psi\rangle⊗|\chi\rangle\\
\\
|\psi'\chi'\rangle=|\psi'\rangle⊗|\chi'\rangle
\end{cases}$$

(For the sake of simplicity, I omit the $(1)$ and $(2)$ labels)
\begin{align}
\langle\psi'\chi'\big|\psi\chi\rangle
& = \big\langle(|\psi'\rangle⊗|\chi'\rangle)\big|(|\psi\rangle⊗|\chi\rangle)\big\rangle
\\ & = \big(\langle\psi'|⊗\langle\chi'|\big)\big|\big(|\psi\rangle⊗|\chi\rangle\big)
\\ & = \Big[\langle\psi'|\big(|\psi\rangle⊗|\chi\rangle\big)\Big]⊗\Big[\langle\chi'|\big(|\psi\rangle⊗|\chi\rangle\big)\Big]
\\ & = \Big[\langle\psi'|\psi\rangle⊗\langle\psi'|\chi\rangle\Big]⊗\Big[\langle\chi'|\psi\rangle⊗\langle\chi'|\chi\rangle\Big]
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please clarify. Do you ask, wether one may derive F-8 by using F-9 and the expansions of $$|\phi(j)\rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i |u_i(j)\rangle $$, where $j\in\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$?

Comment: I have just edited the question, I hope now it is a little clearer.

Comment: You can't take inner product between different vector spaces, like you do in the last line.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Equation (F-8) in the text you've quoted is a definition, and as such it cannot be derived from anything. If things go well, and you have previous structures that you want it to relate to, then you can *justify* the definition, but it is still a novel statement about what structure you're imposing on the new object (i.e. the tensor-product space) you've just defined.